# Why doesn't Moeka believe the D-mail Okabe sent from her phone?

Tags: steins-gate

> In the anime, under the pretext of sending a D-mail that asks her to change her phone, Moeka sends herself the location of the IBN 5100 (the shrine). Her past self then steals the IBN from the shrine. Okabe tries to undo this, by sending a message along the lines of "Shrine is a trap. Don't go there" from her phone. However, it is stated that she didn't believe that message, and stole the IBN from the shrine. Okabe then concludes that in order for her to believe the message, it must come from FB.

My question is, why would Moeka believe the first message, but not the second (sent by Okabe)? Both the messages were sent from the same phone, so why believe one but not the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Moeka was **incredibly desperate** and she didn't really have a lot of leads for the IBN5100. It would have been highly possible she checked it regardless. I believe Okabe says the same thing.